# GNU Screen: Reverse focus tabbing

Tags: gnu-screen

Is it possible to bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch focus to the previous window in the list (much like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>p</kbd> but changing the focus)?

Specifically, I want to skip from the first to the last. For example, here is a screen profile:

```
# Vertical split with two on right
#
# +---+---+
# |   |   |
# |   |---|
# |   |   |
# +---+---+
#
split -v
screen bash
title "main"
focus
split
screen bash
title "script"
focus
screen bash
title "interpreter"
focus left

# ctrl+a navigating regions
bind j focus down
bind k focus up
bind h focus left
bind l focus right
```

Focus starts in the top left screen. I'd like to jump straight to the bottom right. I can do this by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice. Is there a single command and, if so, how could I bind this to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>?

#### Edit

Have just found <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> switches to the next window as well (strangely not `info`). I'm on `Screen version 4.01.00devel (GNU) 2-May-06`

#### Good workaround

Add the following to your screen profile (or `~/.screenrc`)

```
## ctrl+a navigating regions
bindkey "^j" focus down
bindkey "^k" focus up
bindkey "^h" focus left
bindkey "^l" focus right
```

Now you can zip around quickly by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd>/<kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd>/<kbd>l</kbd> in a `vim`-esque style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command you're looking for is `focus prev`.

Unfortunately, there is no way to bind <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, since `bind` does not allow for modifier keys, and <kbd>Tab</kbd> is equivalent to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> (which also explains why it's bound to `focus` instead of `info`), so you'd have to bind it to a different key.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my ~/.screenrc

```
bindkey "^k" focus prev
bindkey "^l" focus next
```

Need to activate if ~/.screenrc does not already exist:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd>, `source ~/.screenrc`

Then we can:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> to cycle to the next split screen

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> for cycle to the previous split screen!

UPDATE:

Having used this screen config for a day, I find that I somehow messed up other keyboard shortcuts. For example, when I press "Esc" in Vim to come out of editing mode, the screen was focusing on the previous screen instead!

So I cancelled the shortcuts I created by coming out of all the split screens, removing the ~/.screenrc file and starting again.

To be honest, I can live with just using Crtl-a, Shift to cycle though split screens, given the consequences of messing up other shortcut keys!

Answer (score 0):

`focus prev` and `focus next` can switch region no matter it's the last or first

Also you can use multiple focus in one bind, add below to .screenrc can replace focus left and right when use a 3x2 region layout

```
bindkey "^a^o" eval "focus next" "focus next"
bindkey "^a^y" eval "focus prev" "focus prev"
```